# Persist Activity fails in wf4 workflow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I am having a problem Persisting a workflow in wf4.

I cannot persist the workflow using the Persist Activity.
Nor can I persist the workflow from a method contained in a class I have injected into the workflow which I then call from inside the workflow using an InvokeMethod activity

If I do:

```
workflowApp = new WorkflowApplication(new actBTX(), inParams);
workflowApp.Run();
workflowApp.Persist();
```

in the factory method that creates the workflows then I can see the workflow persist.

I have tested my workflows to see if I am in a NoPersistZone using:

```
        var prop = context.Properties.Find("System.Activities.NoPersistProperty");
        IsInNoPersistScope.Set(context, prop != null);
```

and it seems I am not.

The fact that I can persist when I am 'outside' the workflow suggests to me that it is not a problem with the variable types that are in the workflow.

When persistence fails it stops the whole workflow dead if I use the Persist activity.
The method call throws an exception:

```
 Exception: The operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:02:00
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this is probably a retarded question, but have you configured SQL persistence for your host? I presume it's a custom workflowservicehost?

Comment: If you host in IIS and use SqlWorkflowInstanceStore, it's relatively easy to get everything working. In that case you normally don't need to explicitly persist.

Comment: @x0n Yes the SQL store is configured.  I can persist if I use workflowApp.Persist(); from th emethod that runs the workflow.

Comment: @TrueWill  Thanks for the suggestion however I am using the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore.

Answer (score 4):

Ok We worked it out.

There is a data object that doesn't serialise nicely.
When Persist hits it it crashes silently (which is a bad thing).

We suspect that workflowApp.Persist() works because the workflow is not fully initialized in the time between

```
workflowApp.Run();
workflowApp.Persist();
```